# asp.net web form Custom Router Handler

Tags: c#, asp.net, internationalization, webforms, routes

I am using a custom route handler for a webforms application.  I am using routes to determine localization.  ie:
     if the url has ***es*** or ***fr*** in the route it will load either spanish or french resources.

for example:

www.someroute/es/checkstuff/checkstuff.aspx

will load:

www.someroute/checkstuff/checkstuff.aspx with the spanish resources.

I am configuring the custom routes in global.asax via:

```
protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    }

    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        foreach (var value in _customRoutes)
        {
            routes.Add(value.RouteName, new Route(value.Route, new CustomRouteHandler(value.ResolvedRoute)));
        }
    }
```

where _customroutes is a list of routes.

Is there a way to do this with some kind of pattern matching so I can avoid adding a specific route for each page in the application.  While I know I could use a t4 template to generate the routes, I guess I am looking for a dynamic way to create the list

Answer (score 2):

I discovered that it was simpler to use MapPageroute than route.Add.  With MapPageRoute I was able to use wildcards and with two entries:

```
        routes.MapPageRoute("Spanish", "es/{*page}", "~/{page}");
        routes.MapPageRoute("Kreyol", "fr/{*page}", "~/{page}");
```

I was able to provide the required routing for Spanish and Kreole pages.

Thanks to all for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I would handle the language-part through some plain old Rewrite with an `HttpModule` in the `BeginReguest` handler and let the `Routing` engine take care of the rest.

Remember that the `Routing` mechanism takes place far later than `BeginRequest` so you can safely determine the language, set the `CultureInfo` on your thread and rewrite the request url to no contain the language-part, and your `Routing` would never know about it.